# julia savefig() saves wrong marker shape

Tags: matplotlib, plot, julia, scatter, savefig

The code is to using `PyPlot` to scatter and save in julia.

```
using PyPlot;pygui(true)

fig = figure()
for i = 1:400

    scatter([i,i+1], [i+1, i+2], color = "blue", s = 0.1)
end
PyPlot.savefig("1.png", figsize = (16, 9),dpi = 1200, bbox_inches="tight")
```

But the plot result and saved figure is different:
What I want is some simple dots:
[image]

But in saved figure the marker shape is circles :
[image]

As you can see, the marker type is changed.
I found this only occurs when scattering highly dense dots. How should I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I just had the exact same problem. The only way I figured out was to set `markeredgecolor="none"`, that got rid of the circles around the dots.
Might not be the most efficient solution, but at least I could produce the plots I needed.